# Crypto++ library link error using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors, crypto++

I'm trying to use the Crypto++ librairy in my project (windows application). Using it, include, compilation work fine, but impossible to deal with the link error

Here is some exemple of link errors, there is more, but don't think it's revelant to copy paste all of them

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl CryptoV2::encrypt(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?encrypt@CryptoV2@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V23@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall PStore::storeReversibleCrypt(wchar_t *,char *)" (?storeReversibleCrypt@PStore@@QAEXPA_WPAD@Z)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl CryptoV2::hashPassword(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?hashPassword@CryptoV2@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V23@0@Z)

fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Basically, I add the "Win32\Output\Release" directory of crypto++ to my linker's additionnal library directories properties, and also the main folder to my C/C++'s General's property "Additional Include Directories"

I've tried a lot of thinks, like adding the library as a new project (same errors), adding all cpp files to my project and compiling with it (not compiling), adding only .cpp files I was using (not realistic, too much), linking all different folder of the cryptopp610 releases (cryptdll, cryptlib, dll_output, Output, same errors), and now, I don't really know what more I can try. I makre also a lots of search, trying all solution I saw (don't remember all of them), still the same problems. I also try to create a new project to add crypto++ without long compilation or mysterious problem, but I also get linker error.

Do anyone got any advice to help me ? Anyway, thank's a lot, and pardon my English

**EDIT**: Need to add that on the new blank project, I get 63 unresolved external symbol, so I think I forgot to do some basic stuff, but can't figure out which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl CryptoV2::encrypt(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?encrypt@CryptoV2@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V23@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall PStore::storeReversibleCrypt(wchar_t *,char *)" (?storeReversibleCrypt@PStore@@QAEXPA_WPAD@Z)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl CryptoV2::hashPassword(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?hashPassword@CryptoV2@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V23@0@Z)
```

The missing symbols are not from Crypto++. Crypto++ uses the `CryptoPP` namespace. The missing symbols are from the `CryptoV2` namespace or class. I'm guessing that's another crypto library.

You were right in adding directories and a library to the linker settings. However, you need to do it for the `CryptoV2` library (in addition to the Crypto++ library).

For completeness, it looks like these are missing:

```
std::string CryptoV2::encrypt(std::string);
std::string CryptoV2::hashPassword(std::string, std::string);
```

Comment: CryptoV2 is just my class that use Cryptopp, also when I comment all cryptopp's stuff in my classes, I don't get the errors anymore.

Comment: I think you were right in your post, one of the first thinks I try was commenting crypto++ stuff to see if I still get errors, but now they are still here, so it's a problem from my new cpp file that is not linking. Still don't find how to fix it, but thank's for seeing I was looking for the wrong problem

Answer (score 0):

It could be Ws2_32.lib there is missing from the linker

Comment: Added, but still the same errors. Thank's for trying !

Answer (score -1):

add `#include "dll.h"` like stated in the Readme:

> To use the Crypto++ DLL in your application, #include "dll.h" before including any other Crypto++ header files, and place the DLL in the same directory as your .exe file. dll.h includes the line #pragma comment(lib, "cryptopp") so you don't have to explicitly list the import library in your project settings.

https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/Readme.txt#L136